# PHP Warning: Missing argument 1 for __()

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

Saludos, hice para uno de mis sitios de wordpress un archivo .php que contiene todas las tags con los enlaces correspondientes dichas publicaciones. No tengo muchos conocimientos de php, el archivo que hice lo construí basicamente modificando el archivo original destinado para las categorias. Aparentemente funciona bien, pero en el log de cpanel estoy mirando un monton de errores, aqui va un ejemplo:

> PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for __(), called in /home/wksxspir/public_html/wp-content/themes/tube/all_tag.php on line 48 and defined in /home/wksxspir/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 201

---

El mismo error se repite una y otra vez y no tengo idea de como resolverlo, no quiero ponerme a tocar cosas y terminar estropeando mi sitio

El archivo que hice es all_tag.php, en la linea 48 de dicho archivo esta esto:

```
echo '<div class="buttons"><a class="btn" href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>View All '. $tag->name.'</a></div>';
```

En la linea 201 del archivo l10n.php se encuentra esto:

```
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
```

Que debo hacer?, agradeceria sus sugerencias.

Comment: Es posible que incluyas tu codigo, en fin, del archivo que te indica el wordpress, para asi poder ayudarte

Comment: A cual código te refieres, el que he creado yo?, quieres que lo copie completo por aquí?

Comment: Me refiero al archivo que tiene el error, l10n.php para poder observar que error tienes en la funcion, o en alguna otra parte del codigo.

Comment: Esta es la funcion completa en esa parte del codigo...el error se indica en esta parte :  * @return string Translated text.
 */
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
 return translate( $text, $domain );
}

/**

Comment: Creo que encontre el problema, ya he hecho la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

#### Vamos por partes

En la linea **48** haces lo siguiente:

```
echo '<div class="buttons"><a class="btn" href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>View All '. $tag->name.'</a></div>';
```

**Pero, si analizas la linea, encontraras que estas llamando a tu funcion `__()` sin pasarle ningun argumento:**

```
sprintf( __( ), $tag->name )
```

**Mientras que la declaracion de la funcion es:**

```
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' );
```

*La traduccion literal de tu error es:*

> Esta perdido el argumento 1 de la funcion __()...

Tienes **2** soluciones:

1. Agregas el primer parametro a la funcion.

   #### sprintf( __("Hola Mundo"), $tag->name )
2. Agregas un parametro por defecto como lo haces con el parametro `$domain`

   #### function __( $text = 'Hola Mundo', $domain = 'default' );

Comment: He resuelto parcialmente el problema, la opción 1 funciono para mi, en el log de mi sitio ya no se muestra el error que se generaba en all_tags.php, pero hay una cosa : mi sitio se traduce automáticamente, pero en esta zona solo se muestra la versión original  (misitio.com/tags) , pero en las otras versiones muestra un error 500  (misitio.com/es/tags) solo sucede en esta parte de mi sitio, que la parte que hice yo...a parte de que esta pagina en particular tarda mucho en cargar. Agradezco tu ayuda, ojala y tuvieras alguna sugerencia para lo nuevo que comento.

Comment: Me parece genial que te haya funcionado! Recuerda que si tienes otra duda puedes formularla, si aumentas tu reputacion puedes ir al chat y allí podrás conversar cuando respondamos tus preguntas